# RaisePropertyChanged - error while converting code from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net-2010, inotifypropertychanged

I want to convert the following piece of C# Code to VB.NET

```
/// <summary>
/// Attempts to raise the PropertyChanged event, and invokes the virtual AfterPropertyChanged
/// method, regardless of whether the event was raised or not.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="propertyName">
/// The property which was changed.
/// </param>

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.VerifyProperty(propertyName);

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            //Get the cached event args.
            PropertyChangedEventArgs args = GetPropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);

            //Raise the PropertyChanged event.
            handler(this, args);
        }
    }
```

After Conversion, the VB Code is:

```
''' <summary>
''' Attempts to raise the PropertyChanged event, and invokes the virtual AfterPropertyChanged
''' method, regardless of whether the event was raised or not.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="propertyName">
''' The property which was changed.
''' </param>
Protected Sub RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
    Me.VerifyProperty(propertyName)

    Dim handler As PropertyChangedEventHandler = Me.PropertyChanged

    If handler IsNot Nothing Then
        'Get the cached event args.
        Dim args As PropertyChangedEventArgs = GetPropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)

        'Raise the PropertyChanged event.
        handler.Invoke(Me, args)
    End If
End Sub
```

I used the Telerik Code Converter which does not give perfect conversion with respect to Events and XML Attributes etc.

The problem is, Visual Studio shows the following error:
Error      103      'Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

Can you kindly help me with this as I am not good at VB.NET Syntaxes and such :(

Comment: Dim handler As PropertyChangedEventHandler = Me.PropertyChanged

Comment: In VB, you have to use AddressOf a lot when you are working with events. So maybe you could use "AddressOf Me.PropertyChanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace
Dim handler As PropertyChangedEventHandler = Me.PropertyChanged
with
Dim handler As PropertyChangedEventHandler = Me.PropertyChangedEvent

Answer (score 1):

You need define PropertyChanged variable first!

like this:
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;